# R calculating % for rows based on total of all rows

Tags: r

I have this data set

```
Covered Status  Lives
A   76042802
B   111539028
C   18416169
D   17484215
E   36499828
```

I need to calculate the % for each row, the result being as follows

```
Covered Status  Lives   %
A   76042802    29.2%
B   111539028   42.9%
C   18416169    7.1%
D   17484215    6.7%
E   36499828    14.0%
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this calculation?

Comment: `dat$Lives <- dat$Covered.Status/sum(dat$Covered.Status)` Of course, even more efficient with package data.table: `DT[, Lives:= Covered.Status/sum(Covered.Status)]`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
data$Lives <- data$Status/sum(data$Status)
```